# Store variables from Inline Assembly and use them after the block?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, assembly, yul

Unlike almost all examples of inline assembly usage, I would not like to immediately return the function after doing something in the assembly block.

Rather, I would like to save the result to some Solidity variables, and use them for other logic in the function. For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
fallback() external payable {
    bytes4 calledFunction;
    uint256 returnVal;

    assembly {
        calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
        calledFunction := mload(0) // attempt to retrieve first 4 bytes of calldata and save
        let result := delegatecall(gas(), facet, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
        switch result
        case 0 { 
            revert(0, returndatasize()) 
        } 
        default {
            // returned from the delegate call should be the uint256 that we want
            // so set it to 'returnVal'
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
            returnVal := mload(0)
        }
    }

    // do something with callFunction and returnVal;
    uint256 added = 2 + returnVal
    return calledFunction, added;
}
```

However, I can not seem to properly set the inline assembly memory values to the `calledFunction` and `returnVal` variables. I think I am either doing something wrong, or this is a fundamentally impossible operation.

I would love to learn if and how memory is scoped inside the assembly block, and would appreciate some guidance here. Thank you!

Comment: Just change `returnVal = mload(0)` to `returnVal := mload(0)`, your code is fine otherwise. After the assembly block, `returnVal` holds the value returned by the delegated call.

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo, but from my experimenting, I am still doing something wrong with the above code.

Comment: In particular, `returnVal` is not equal to the expected value of the uint256 returned from the function. I believe method of `returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())` `returnVal := mload(0)` might be problematic but am unsure of the correct way to do this.

Comment: Can you show the content of the function you are calling with the `delegatecall` ?

Comment: Sure! ```contract MyContract {
    function myFunction(bytes4 _calledFunction, uint256 _returnVal) external {
        console.log("_calledFunction:");
        console.logBytes4(_calledFunction);
    }
}```

Comment: But if that's the function you are calling with `delegatecall` , it doesn't return anything ? Can you put all of your code in the question (caller + callee) so that I can see more clearly where your issue is ?